# How to turn these voronoi texture stars white

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

So how do I turn those black star areas white, if I reverse the color ramp OR use an invert function is almost acts as a clipping mask for the wavy purple-blue texture "behind it"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for instance take the star from the Voronoi and use that to mix white with the current color output:

[image]